# How to make yum also install the manuals?

Tags: yum, manual

```
yum install libevent-dev
```

Now I have installed libevent,but its manuals are not installed:

```
[root@xx test]# man event_base_loop
Cannot open the message catalog "man" for locale "zh_CN.UTF-8"
(NLSPATH="<none>")

No manual entry for event_base_loop
```

How to make yum also install manuals?

Comment: You may want to mention what distro and version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `libevent-devel` has the function-level man pages under its private documentation directory instead of the public man directory. [Log a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/).

Comment: How to fix it manually?

Comment: Copy or symlink the files.

Comment: Where is the private documentation directory?

Comment: `/usr/share/doc/$PACKAGENAME-$PACKAGEVERSION`

Answer (score 0):

It probably is installed--`libevent` just doesn't install separate documentation for each individual function.  To see the documentation for `libevent`, use:

```
man 3 event
```